# no global superior knowledge error upon adding new entry (change suffix?)

Tags: ldap, openldap

Openldap 2.4.31 is installed on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to add the first entry to the LDAP, it says:
 
`adding new entry "dc=abc,dc=com"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge`

This is the command I use in CLI:
`ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f import-org.ldif`

From various blogs I understood that  this happens because the the new entry with dn `dc=abc,dc=com` cannot be added to the LDAP with suffix `dc=xyz,dc=com`.

Installation process defines the LDAP suffix without prompting to set a custom one. 
I read a bunch of manuals and blogs and failed to find any document that describes how to change or add a new suffix or any other way to solve the issue in this version of openldap.

Comment: OpenLDAP as most LDAP directory services support multiple LDAP suffixes. They must be declared in the configuration.
How to do this depends on the version of the server. And it's usually documented.

Comment: That's the point, I couldn't find where it is documented for openldap 2.4.31. Could you?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I'm not working with OpenLDAP.

Comment: You've probably defined a database with the suffix "DC=xyz,DC=com", so to use a different suffix you need to define a new database with that suffix.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the document that describes how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[You need to add the new Suffix.](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch11/multi-dit.html)

This example assumes that dc=example,dc=com exisits and you desire to add dc=example,dc=net

You can do this via LDIF with Something like:

```
# add example.net to an existing LDAP server
version: 1

dn: dc=example,dc=net
dc: example
description: Example Network Operations
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example, Inc.

dn: ou=people, dc=example,dc=net
ou: people
description: All people in organisation
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

Than add the entry as desired under the new suffix.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code. I just copied it as it is. The result is the same.
Perhaps anything wrong in the command line? This is the command line:
`ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f example-org.ldif`

Comment: You would need to of course modify the file to meet your environment.